# Support encryption algorithm "ECIES" using cipher with dart . language

Tags: java, flutter, dart, encryption

I currently have a Java class like below:

```java
class Sample {
    private SetPinEncryptedDTO createSetPinEncryptedPayload(PublicKeyDTO publicKeyDTO, String plainPin) throws Exception {
        final String AES_CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING";
        final String ECC_CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION = "ECIES";
        // encrypt PIN with AES
        byte[] aesKey = generateAESKey(256).getEncoded();
        byte[] encryptedPin = encrypt(AES_CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION, aesKey, plainPin.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), new byte[16]);
        // encrypt AES key with ECC using the received public key. Public key is encoded with Base64
        PublicKey publicKey = readEncodedECCPublicKey(Base64.decodeBase64(publicKeyDTO.getPublicKey()));
        byte[] encryptedAesKey = eccEncrypt(ECC_CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION, publicKey, aesKey);
        // create a payload
        SetPinEncryptedDTO setPinDTO = new SetPinEncryptedDTO();
        setPinDTO.setPin(Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedPin)); // encode encrypted PIN with Base64
        setPinDTO.setEncryptedSymmetricKey(Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedAesKey));// encode encrypted AES key with Base64
        setPinDTO.setChecksum(new HmacUtils(HmacAlgorithms.HMAC_SHA_256, aesKey).hmacHex(plainPin.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        return setPinDTO;
    }

    public static SecretKey generateAESKey(int length) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(length);
        return keyGen.generateKey();
    }

    public static byte[] encrypt(String cipherTransformation, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] message, byte[] ivBytes) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
        return aesCipher.doFinal(message);
    }

    public static ECPublicKey readEncodedECCPublicKey(byte[] bytesKey) throws Exception {
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
        X509EncodedKeySpec x509EncodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bytesKey);
        return (ECPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(x509EncodedKeySpec);
    }

    public static byte[] eccEncrypt(String eccCipherTransformation, PublicKey publicKey, byte[] plainBytes) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(eccCipherTransformation, BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        return cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);
    }
}
```

I want to convert that class to Dart, and I have written that class into the following:

```dart
class Sample {
  static Future<Uint8List> generateAESKey() async {
    final algorithm = better_cryptography.AesGcm.with256bits(nonceLength: 32);
    final key = algorithm.newNonce();
    return Uint8List.fromList(key);
  }

  static Uint8List encryptAES(String cipherTransformation, Uint8List keyBytes,
      Uint8List plainText, Uint8List ivBytes) {
    final params = PaddedBlockCipherParameters(
      ParametersWithIV<KeyParameter>(KeyParameter(keyBytes), ivBytes),
      null, // Using PKCS7 padding by default
    );

    PaddedBlockCipher cipher = PaddedBlockCipher(cipherTransformation)
      ..init(true, params);

    Uint8List encrypted = cipher.process(plainText);
    return encrypted;
  }

  static String eccEncrypt(String eccCipherTransformation,
      ECPublicKey publicKey, Uint8List plaintext) {
    var rnd = getSecureRandom();
    var domainParams = ECDomainParameters("secp256r1");
    // 1. Create ephemeral key pair
    var ephKeyPair = (KeyGenerator("EC")
          ..init(ParametersWithRandom(
              ECKeyGeneratorParameters(domainParams), rnd)))
        .generateKeyPair();

    // 3. Get full point to ECDH shared secret, derive AES key via HKDF
    var sharedSecretECPointUncomp =
        (publicKey.Q! * (ephKeyPair.privateKey as ECPrivateKey).d)!
            .getEncoded(false);
    var ephPublicKeyUncomp =
        (ephKeyPair.publicKey as ECPublicKey).Q!.getEncoded(false);
    var aesKey = hkdf(ephPublicKeyUncomp, sharedSecretECPointUncomp);

    // 4. Encrypt via AES-256, GCM
    var nonce = rnd.nextBytes(16);
    var ciphertextTag = (GCMBlockCipher(AESEngine())
          ..init(true,
              AEADParameters(KeyParameter(aesKey), 128, nonce, Uint8List(0))))
        .process(plaintext);

    // 5. Concatenate (ephemeral public key|nonce|tag|ciphertext), Base64 encode and return
    return base64.encode(ephPublicKeyUncomp +
        nonce +
        ciphertextTag.sublist(ciphertextTag.length - 16) +
        ciphertextTag.sublist(0, ciphertextTag.length - 16));
  }

  static basic_utils.SecureRandom getSecureRandom() {
    List<int> seed =
        List<int>.generate(32, (_) => Random.secure().nextInt(256));
    return FortunaRandom()..seed(KeyParameter(Uint8List.fromList(seed)));
  }

  static Uint8List hkdf(var ephPublicKeyUnc, var sharedSecretEcPointUnc) {
    var master = Uint8List.fromList(ephPublicKeyUnc + sharedSecretEcPointUnc);
    var aesKey = Uint8List(32);
    (HKDFKeyDerivator(SHA256Digest())..init(HkdfParameters(master, 32, null)))
        .deriveKey(null, 0, aesKey, 0);
    return aesKey;
  }

  static String hMacSha256(String data, Uint8List key) {
    var hMacSha256 = crypto.Hmac(crypto.sha256, key);
    return hMacSha256.convert(utf8.encode(data)).toString();
  }

  static Future<ECPublicKey> readEncodedECCPublicKey(String key) async {
    ASN1Parser parser = ASN1Parser(Uint8List.fromList(base64.decode(key)));
    ASN1Sequence topLevelSeq = parser.nextObject() as ASN1Sequence;
    ECPoint? ecPoint;
    // Extracting ECPoint
    try {
      ASN1Sequence publicKeySeq = topLevelSeq.elements![0] as ASN1Sequence;
      ASN1BitString publicKeyBitString =
      topLevelSeq.elements![1] as ASN1BitString;
      List<int> publicKeyBytes = publicKeyBitString.stringValues!;
      ecPoint = ECCurve_secp256r1().curve.decodePoint(publicKeyBytes);
    } catch (e) {}
    // Creating ECPublicKey object
    final keyParams = ECCurve_secp256r1();
    final ecPublicKey = ECPublicKey(ecPoint, keyParams);
    return ecPublicKey;
  }

  static String hMacHex(
      String hMacAlgorithm, Uint8List key, List<int> message) {
    var hMacSha256 = crypto.Hmac(crypto.sha256, key);
    var hMac = hMacSha256.convert(message);
    return hex.encode(hMac.bytes);
  }

  static Future<SetPinEncryptedDTO> createSetPinEncryptedPayload(
      String publicKeyFromServer, String plainPin) async {
    const String AES_CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS7";
    const String ECC_CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION = "ECIES";
    const String HMAC_ALGORITHM = "SHA-256";

    // Encrypt PIN with AES
    final aesKey = await generateAESKey();
    final encryptedPin = encryptAES(AES_CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION, aesKey,
        Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(plainPin)), Uint8List(16));

    // Encrypt AES key with ECC using the received public key. Public key is encoded with Base64.
    final publicKey = await readEncodedECCPublicKey(publicKeyFromServer);
    final encryptedAesKey =
        eccEncrypt(ECC_CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION, publicKey, aesKey);

    // Create a payload
    final setPinDTO = SetPinEncryptedDTO();
    setPinDTO.pin =
        base64.encode(encryptedPin); // Encode encrypted PIN with Base64
    setPinDTO.encryptedSymmetricKey =
        encryptedAesKey; // Encode encrypted AES key with Base64
    setPinDTO.checksum = hMacHex(HMAC_ALGORITHM, aesKey, utf8.encode(plainPin));
    return setPinDTO;
  }
}
```

All the functions in function createSetPinEncryptedPayload work and it seem very well, but encryptedAesKey is wrong. In Java, `Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedAesKey)` returns a character string with length 156, but in Dart length is 172. I don't know which is wrong. How do I fix this?

Comment: What did you do to see if the chosen primitives are correct? How did you come up with HKDF and HMAC-SHA-256? How are you going to make sure that the ciphertext looks the same if ECIES creates an ephemeral key pair to derive the AES key? I'd suggest you perform a lot more research, then create a decryption routine for both. Decryption *is deterministic* and you can then step through to see what is happening. Note that Bouncy Castle is also open source, if you link the source you can step through the encryption / decryption code.

Comment: Why do you encrypt the plaintext (`plainPin`) with AES and the AES key (`aesKey`) with ECIES (and generate a MAC for authentication) in the Java code? ECIES is a hybrid scheme that does all this for you under the hood. So why don't you just encrypt the plaintext (`plainPin`) with ECIES?

Comment: Apart from that you have to keep in mind (especially cross-platform) that there are different ECIES standards. So if you use the ECIES implementation of a certain provider, you have to use the same standard on the other side (and if you implement it yourself with the corresponding effort, you have to follow the specification exactly).